# The ViewData item that has the key 'Key' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' in iis7.5

Tags: model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

**Solved - Check comments**

I have a problem when I deploy my code to IIS 7.5, The code works fine in localhost but crashes when I deploy it.

I have two methods that are almost exactly the same where one of them works both in localhost and IIS and one only works in localhost

**Works in IIS 7.5 and localhost**

**Controller**

```
var CustomerList = (from Cust in db.Customers
                   select Cust).ToList();
ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(CustomerList, "CustomerId", "Name");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, ViewBag.CustomerList as SelectList, "-Select Customer-", new { id = "CustomerList" })
```

**Model**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Applications = new HashSet<Application>();
            this.ChangeRequests = new HashSet<ChangeRequest>();
            this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ChangeRequest> ChangeRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

.

.

**Don't Work in IIS 7.5 but works in localhost**

**Controller**

```
var ModificationList = (from m in db.Modifications
                        select m).ToList();
ViewBag.ModificationList = new SelectList(ModificationList, "ModificationId", "Code");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModificationId, ViewBag.ModificationList as SelectList, "-Select Change-", new { id = "ModificationList" })
```

**Model**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Modification
    {
        public Modification()
        {
            this.ChangeRequests = new HashSet<ChangeRequest>();
        }

        public int ModificationId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChangeRequest> ChangeRequests { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Error I get when trying to enter the deployed site**

```
> The ViewData item that has the key 'ModificationId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

.

```
> [InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'ActionId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.GetSelectData(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name) +442
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +136
   ASP._Page_Views_ChangeRequest_CreateChangeView_cshtml.Execute() in d:\WebSites\TeamWeb\ChangeRequestSite\Test\Views\ChangeRequest\CreateChangeView.cshtml:153
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: **SOLVED** - 

The problem was that that the .dll files didnt update correctly in the
iis deploy, so the controller changes never was updated but the view
changes were.
 
So the error just stated that the ViewBag was null.
 
I added "if(ViewBag.ModificationList != null){'Dropdown'} statement
and when the dropdown did not show I figured out the problem.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem was that that the .dll files didnt update correctly in the
>   iis deploy, so the controller changes never was updated but the view
>   changes were. So the error just stated that the ViewBag was null. I
>   added "if(ViewBag.ModificationList != null){'Dropdown'} statement and
>   when the dropdown did not show I figured out the problem. Hope this
>   helps someone else in the future!